# Why does mypy complain when a subtype is returned when using TypeVar?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I wonder why this example doesn't pass mypy check:

```py
from typing import Optional, TypeVar


class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("B")


T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)


def foo(x: T) -> Optional[T]:
    if type(x) is B:
        return B()
    return None
```

The mypy error:

```
toy.py:18:16: error: Incompatible return value type (got "B", expected "Optional[T]")  [return-value]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Isn't `B` a valid type for `T`?

Comment: so, your function always returns `B | None`, basically, but if you are using a type variable, if you pass it `A` it should return `A | None`. I guess it isn't smart enough to figure out than in every other case, it is really returning `None`, you cant fix this with an overload either I'm afraid, because they would be unsafely overlapping (see: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#type-checking-the-variants)

Answer (score 0):

It's bit of an odd one, but I've found the below does pass type checks:

```py
from typing import Optional, TypeVar


class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("B")


T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)


def foo(x: T) -> Optional[T]:
    if type(x) is B:
        return type(x)() # Here's the modification
    return None
```

Switching `B` for `type(x)` works because `type(x)` has been narrowed by the if statement. This should be exactly equivalent, so in some way it's a bug in type checkers, but thought the workaround might be helpful.

UPDATE: This appears to only solve the bug in pyright and not mypy

Comment: It doesn't change the error message with Mypy 1.8.0. Which type checker did you use?

Comment: Oh I used pyright apologies - was thinking mypy also had this behaviour. The original bug appeared in pyright as well, but I'm wondering if the type narrowing in if statements is a pyright only thing